# Is .app domain no needs to have a sepearte SSL certificate

Tags: ssl, web, https, dns

I am a newbie in web development, i heard about .app domains from google with builtin https security.

IS .app domain no needs to have a sepearate ssl certificate since it is builtin and  all request are https by default.

https://techcrunch.com/2018/05/01/google-is-launching-app-domains-the-first-tlds-secured-with-built-in-https/

Comment: All requests are HTTPS by default from browser because 1) Google added its whole TLD `.APP` to the HSTS preloading list and 2) Browsers use this list - hardcoded in their source - to only attempt HTTPS requests and never pure HTTP one. For any HTTPS communication to work you need to have a proper certificate in place. This should have been explained to you when you were registering your `.app` domain, this is a requirement by registrars to show a text about it, coming from registry regulations.

Answer (score 1):

As you can read from the link:

> Google is **requiring** HTTPS for all. app websites

So you buy domain but you should take care for hosting and for certificate. If Google offer bundle with domain, hosting and certificate this do not change the things. You need certificate independently from the provider of the service.